# How to send FormData from angular to nestjs

Tags: angular, nestjs

I want to send a `FormData` from angular to nestjs. In my angular component :

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('studentFile', file)
formData.append('studentName', name)

const headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("Accept", "application/json").set('Content-Type', 'application/json')

this.httpClient.post("http://localhost:3000", formData, { headers }).subscribe(response => { })
```

When I print formData is not empty.

In my nestjs:

```
@Post()
create(@Body() model: any) {
  console.log(model) // is null
  return "Response"
}
```

**NOTE:** I do not want to use `@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor(...))` because with the help of **[ftp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp)** package I want to save file in the another server not
in a directory of the project ...

How can I get `studentFile` and `studentName` in the create method.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to send `FormData`, but you're telling the server that it's in the format of `application/json`. These are not interchangeable, and should not be thought of as such. You either need to send the data as `multipart/form-data` and use `multer` manually, or the `FileInterceptor` which you've said you don't want to do, or you need to send actual JSON data instead of `FormData`. It doesn't make sense to mix the two content types.